"FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" when updating a row
I have two entities in my Room database:
@Entity(
    tableName = "user",
    primaryKeys = ["id"],
)
data class User(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val userId: Long,

    // Other columns here
)

@Entity(
    tableName = "entry",
    primaryKeys = ["id"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = User::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["user_id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
        ),
    ],
)
data class Entry(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    val userId: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "active")
    val active: Boolean,
)

I also have DAOs to operate on these. The relevant DAO method is this one that updates the "active" column for entries:
@Query("SELECT * FROM entry WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun getEntry(id: Long): Entry?

@Update
suspend fun updateEntry(entry: Entry)

Then, I have this code that updates the active status:
suspend fun setActive(entryId: Long) {
    val entry = dao.getEntry(entryId)
    entry?.let {
        dao.updateEntry(entry.copy(active = true))
    }
}

However, in production on some users, calls to the setActive() function throw a SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed. What could be causing this? To my knowledge, the onDelete = CASCADE should delete the entries if a user is deleted. My logs don't seem to indicate whether the throw happens on the getEntry() call or the updateEntry() call.

How could a get fail a foreign key constraint?

I would suggest not using the @Update convenience method, as this will change/set all values.
i.e. the underlying generated SQL is
"UPDATE OR ABORT `entry` SET `id` = ?,`user_id` = ?,`active` = ? WHERE `id` = ?"


and for whatever reason the user_id value is being changed to a value that results in the FK conflict (based upon the code given in the question and therefore not considering the possible impact of other foreign key constraints or even any Triggers).

Instead the suggestion is to use:-
@Query("UPDATE entry SET active = 1 WHERE id=:id")
suspend fun setActive(id: Long)

This will then never try to change the user_id value and is also not subject to multiple (2) suspended functions.

note that this code is in-principle code, it has not been compiled or run and thus may contain small errors
although SET active = true can be used in some cases, the use of true is not available until Android 11 or later.


Thanks, I didn't know about that generated SQL being like that. I investigated the issue a bit more, and the only thing that could affect the foreign key relation is a Room transaction that deleted the user rows. Perhaps there's some concurrency going on where the transaction is still in progress while the update is done on the entry row.
